# Prevent component from being created when inserted as content within another component (angular 2)

Tags: angular2-components

When inserting a component as ng-content of another component, how can I prevent it from being initialized until an expression is true?

```
<ng-content *ngIf="expression"></ng-content>
```

I basically only want the component's ngOnInit method to run once it's actually visible.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap ng-content in'div' element to use *ngIf.

```
<div *ngIf="expression">
<ng-content ></ng-content>
</div>
```